# Laravel whereHas not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a relationship on my User table called 'roles'.

This relationship is:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\RoleUser');
}
```

I am only trying to fetch users that have a role of 3.

My query is:

```
User::where('name', $name)
    ->orWhere('email', $email)
    ->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
        $q->where('id', 3);
    })->get();
```

This, however, is returning all users no matter what their role. I can confirm that all users have roles and the roles relationship is working.

The fields in the role_user table are 'id', 'user_id'

Comment: You have to try this: `$role_id = 3; User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($role_id) {
    $q->where('id', $role_id);
})->get();`

Comment: @HirenGohel See my edit and comment on my answer posted. Your comment is a working solution, but my whereHas was also working in its state but the rest of the code had an issue.

Comment: So you mean to say that your `orWhere` condition not worked right??

Comment: does your role_user table has  role_id column?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue was caused by a previous orWhere clause on the query.

Looking at the original query in the question:

```
User::where('name', $name)
    ->orWhere('email', $email)
    ->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
        $q->where('id', 3);
    })->get();
```

This reads as where the name is 'name' and the user has roles and includes a role of 3. The query was also bringing in any results that had an email that matched my provided email but because it was 'orWhere' it ignored the other requirements.

Comment: Without providing enough detail to explain how to solve the problem, this commentary is is pointless. Imagine yourself getting this information as an answer from another user; would it have **answered** your question? Sure, it might give you a hint where to look in your code, but nobody else can see it. If this is to be accepted as the answer to that question, the question is rendered **unclear** and lacking **enough detail to adequately answer**. If only you have all the details, and are not sharing them, how is this Q&A useful? Please edit and improve.

Comment: @FredGandt Updated my question to show the actual query I had

Comment: @Lovelock - That's a good start; thank you. Can you now add a little more information to the answer to explain how the `orWhere` clause caused the problem, and how you changed the query to solve it?